# Volume of a $n$-simplex in $(n+k)$-dimensions

Tags: geometry, volume, simplex

From [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) the formula for calculating the volume of a $n$-simplex in an $n$-dimensional space is given. Please how does one find the volume of the same simplex existing in a $(n+k)$-dimensional space

> $k>=1$.

For example, say we have the following vertices $$ v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, v_{4}$$ from a 3-simplex, the volume would be

$$
 \frac{1}{3!}\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
v_{1} & v_{2} & v_{3} & v_{4}\\
\end{vmatrix} =
 \frac{1}{3!}\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
v_{1}.x & v_{2}.x & v_{3}.x & v_{4}.x\\
v_{1}.y & v_{2}.y & v_{3}.y & v_{4}.y\\
v_{1}.z & v_{2}.z & v_{3}.z & v_{4}.z\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Now my challenge is getting the volume of some $3$-simplex in any $(3+k)$-dimensional space e.g. say k=2, that would mean the volume of a 3-simplex existing in a 5-dimensional space

Comment: I feel like the simplex being embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ and not $\mathbb{R}^n$ shouldn't matter too much. If you mean $n+k$-dimensional volume, then it's $0$. If you mean $n$-dimensional "surface area", then we could use coordinates in an $n$-dimensional subspace containing said simplex and use the formula you provided.

Comment: @Theorem I feel you but catch this cruise, let say we have a 2-simplex normally existing in 2D space tilted to partially exist in a 3D space (we now have 3D vertices), considering it as a 3-simplex wouldn't make sense because for one an extra vertex would be required even at that just as you pointed out the volume would be zero but the catch to the madness is one being able to compute its surface area as the volume of a 2-simplex with 3D vertices

Comment: Now it would be impossible to use the same formula because we now have extra axes

Comment: Okay so I might not understand the problem you are depicting so tell me if my suggestion fails. I didn't check if it gives you a closed form formula but it is an algorithm: Take the span of the $n$ simplex vertices, obtaining the subspace $V$ I talked about.  Find an orthonormal base $B$ of $V$ (via Gram Schmidt for instance) and now you have an isometry between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $v\rightarrow [v]_B$ that preserves $n$-dim area. My suggestion is to use your formula for the vectors $[v_i]_B\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I am not a maths major so I would really pretend I understand this comment :) but am looking into it, I guess there’s no harm in doing some more research. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Hi @Theorem, Seems I would still be needing your help, would you mind if I post my best attempt at your suggestion in the form of an answer to this question so that you can help correct it by making edits to it

Comment: Sure. Note that I'm still uncertain if the idea I proposed can be developed to an expression that can be computed easily, but if your intention is to program something that calculates it, it's very possible.

Comment: alright then, I would be posting later today. thanks

Comment: hi sorry I couldn’t make it yesterday, for what it’s worth I just posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$-volume of the $n$-simplex with vertices $\vec v_0, …, \vec v_n ∈ \mathbb R^{n + k}$ is

$$\frac{1}{n!}\sqrt{\det(\mathbf A^\mathsf T\mathbf A)}, \quad \text{where } \mathbf A = \begin{bmatrix}\vec v_1 - \vec v_0 & \vec v_2 - \vec v_0 & ⋯ & \vec v_n - \vec v_0\end{bmatrix},$$

because all the entries of $\mathbf A^\mathsf T \mathbf A$ are dot products $(\vec v_i - \vec v_0) \cdot (\vec v_j - \vec v_0)$ which are preserved under any isometry $\mathbb R^n → \mathbb R^{n + k}$, and this reduces to the usual formula $\frac{1}{n!} \lvert\det \mathbf A\rvert$ when $k = 0$.

(Note: the more symmetric formula using the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
\vec v_0 & \vec v_1 & \vec v_2 & ⋯ & \vec v_n \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & ⋯ & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ *only* works in $n$ dimensions. I just fixed an incorrect claim otherwise on Wikipedia.)

Comment: doesn’t seem to work in all cases for example a 2-simplex in a 3D environment with the vertices  $(0,0,0) (3,0,0) (3,3,0)$ returns $0$ as the volume according to this

Comment: @LiNKeR Works for me: $A = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}3&3\\0&3\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, $A^\mathsf TA = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}9&9\\9&18\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, $\det(A^\mathsf TA) = 81$, $\frac{1}{2!}\sqrt{81} = \frac 92$.

Comment: here’s what I mean since $\mathbf A = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 3  \\ 0 & 3  \\ 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} $  and $\mathbf A^\mathsf T = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 3 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} $ thus $\mathbf A^\mathsf T\mathbf A$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
18 & 9 & 0 \\ 9 & 9 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @LiNKeR You have computed $AA^\mathsf T$, not $A^\mathsf TA$.

Comment: it works now, thanks